# Задача на ввод числа в диапазоне и потом работой с этим числом

Tags: c++, сортировка, if

Пользователь вводит целое число в диапозоне от 1 до 999999
если число не четное, то вывести сообщение "Сhislo ne chetnoe"
если число четное разбить число на разряды
занести эти числа в массив
с помощью функции sort отсортировать элементы массива.
Вот что я написал, но застрял.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int chislo;
    cout << "Vvedite chislo ot 1 do 999999: ";
    cin >> chislo;
    int dlinaChisla = 0;
    for (chislo; chislo > 0; chislo /= 10) {
        dlinaChisla = dlinaChisla + 1;
    }
    int array[dlinaChisla];
    
    if ((chislo % 2) != 0) {
        cout << "Сhislo ne chetnoe";
    } else if ((chislo % 2) == 0){
        for (chislo; chislo > 0; chislo = chislo / 10) {
            array[dlinaChisla] = chislo % 10;
            dlinaChisla--;
        } } else {
            cout << "Vvedite chislo tolko v diapazone ot 1 do 999999";
        }
        
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Вы не находите, что тут `for (chislo; chislo > 0; chislo /= 10)` вы в результате обнуляете `chislo`? :) Кстати, `int array[dlinaChisla];` — не соответствует стандарту С++.

Comment: Хм, я думал что в этом выражении я беру Число, говорю что цикл работает пока Число больше 0, и каждый пройденный цикл брать число и делить на 10, этим отсекая 1 цифру от числа. таким образом я нахожу количество цифр в числе, разве нет? прошу прощения я только учусь :) по поводу int array[dlinaChisla]; не знал. Искал как создать массив в зависимости от количества цифр в числе :)

Comment: Да, но ведь **само число** вы при этом уменьшаете и в конечном итоге обнуляете! После цикла ваша `chislo` равно 0...

Comment: Поскольку ``(chislo % 2)`` может быть или 0 или 1, то писать ``else if ((chislo % 2) == 0)`` излишне. Достаточно просто else.

Comment: Если вы полюбопытствуете, сколько десятичных цифр (разрядов) может содержаться в самом большом числе, то вопрос с размером массива не будет вас мучать

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int chislo;
    cout << "Vvedite chislo ot 1 do 999999: ";
    cin >> chislo;
    std::string s = to_string(chislo);
    int* array = new int[s.size()];

    if ((chislo % 2) != 0) {
        cout << "Сhislo ne chetnoe";
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = chislo % 10;
            chislo /= 10;
        }
        sort(array, array + s.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]